# can I have an abstract class inheriting from another abstract class ? (java)

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
public abstract class Two extends One
{
}
```

Class One is defined as

```
public abstract class One
{
}
```

Comment: You could just try it to find out, but the answer is yes.

Comment: +1 Even though you can just try it yourself, I really don't mind that this question gets asked.  There are probably a lot of questions in that category on stackoverflow.

Comment: you can refer this similar question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743584/can-one-abstract-class-extend-another-abstract-class-and-increase-functionality

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and you cannot instantiate it either, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

If you extend a class with an abstract class and do not define or provide the implementation for the base class abstract methods then the child class extending it would automatically become abstract.

Comment: what do you mean by "automatically"? Did you mean you don't have to write the `abstract` keyword?